# How to Uninstall OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I want to switch over my OCaml installation to the method my class has provided. However, I installed OCaml by myself a long time ago and don't know how to uninstall it. It wasn't done using brew; attempting to use `brew uninstall ocaml` results in an error stating no file ocaml exists in brew's directory.

Anyone have a guide or know how I would go about doing this?

OCaml version: 4.02.1
opam version: 1.2.1

Answer (score 2):

So what I ended up doing is updating brew and installing opam and ocaml on top of the existing installations. Everything seems to have worked out fine; I just had to tweak some of the installation settings to make sure the installation worked for the class.

No need to uninstall!

Comment: If you still want to remove the non-Brew installation, you will have to remember how you installed it. Did you install it from source? What is the result of `which ocaml`?

Comment: `which ocaml` provides `Users/____/.ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.2/bin/ocaml`

I honestly don't remember - however, there doesn't seem to be any issues right now with using the brew installation of the latest version. If anything comes up I'll definitely update this question with the complications, and if I figure out why, those explanations as well.

Comment: Just trying to be thorough :) Sorry, I meant `which -a ocaml`, but I understand if you prefer to leave this alone.

Comment: @antron No problem! I just skipped over it since finishing schoolwork > debugging something that's practically working fine, but I followed your instructions and  got the following: `/Users/___/.ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.2/bin/ocaml` and 
`/Users/___/.opam/4.02.1/bin/ocaml`. Looks like I still have two installations! Not really sure how to remove the opam installation though.

Comment: `opam switch remove 4.02.1` should do it for removing the OPAM one. Before that, you may want to check `opam switch -i` to see that you have a `system` switch or some other switch besides `4.02.1` installed. You will also want to switch away from it, like `opam switch system`; ``eval `opam config env` ``.

Comment: Running `opam switch -i` returns `system C system  System compiler (4.02.2)`, and `opam switch system`; eval `opam config env` doesn't seem to be changing anything. Running `opam switch remove 4.02.1` isn't removing the installation either - running opam switch -i still shows both installations. I ended up just rm -rf'ing the 4.02.1 installation.